# Where in the source code is it implemented that iterators from LinkedHashSet and HashSet have different behaviour?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, hashset, linkedhashset

I investigate `LinkedHashSet` and `HashSet`  collections.

I wrote small program:

```
public class LHSTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        output(test(new LinkedHashSet()));
        System.out.println("=========");
        output(test(new HashSet()));

    }
    public static HashSet<MyClass> test(HashSet hashSet){
        hashSet.add(new MyClass(1));
        hashSet.add(new MyClass(2));
        hashSet.add(new MyClass(3));
        hashSet.add(new MyClass(4));
        hashSet.add(new MyClass(5));
         return  hashSet;
    }
    public static void output(HashSet hashSet){
        for(Iterator iterator = hashSet.iterator();iterator.hasNext();){
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }
}

class MyClass{
    int a;
    MyClass(int a){
        this.a =a;
    }
    public int hashCode(){
        return 15-a;
    }
    public String toString()   {
        return  a+"";
    }
}
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
=========
5
4
3
2
1
```

When I saw this behaviour I began research source code of collections.

I noticed that both LinkedHashSet and HashSet use

common `toString()`  realization - from `AbstractCollection`

and common `iterator()` from `HashSet`

What were explain the different output for `LinkedHashSet` and `HashSet` in my code?

### Update after Ivan Babanin answer

For `LinkedHashSet` and `HashSet` invoke different constructors:

for   `LinkedHashSet` -

```
HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean dummy) {
    map = new LinkedHashMap<E,Object>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
}
```

for   `HashSet` -

```
 public HashSet() {
    map = new HashMap<E,Object>();
 }
```

iterator for  both `HashMap` and -`LinkedHasMap` (from `HashSet`)

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return map.keySet().iterator();
 }
```

Research `keySet()` method:

`HashMap`:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
        Set<K> ks = keySet;
        return (ks != null ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet()));
}
```

`LinkedHashMap` cannot especial realization for `keySet` method and uses `HashMap` realization.

`map.keySet().iterator() is` :

```
public class HashMap<K,V>    extends AbstractMap<K,V>    implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable,      Serializable{
     ...
    private final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
          public Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator() {
               return newEntryIterator();
          }
            ...
    }
     ...
}
```

`map.keySet()` returns  same type for `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` therefore invoke same `newEntryIterator()` method.

Is it wrong statement?

### for EJP update

I navigate to `HashSet#iterator`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No. map.keySet() returns the same type, but it's an inner class, and the enclosing type is different, so when it calls a method of the enclosing type, polymorphism occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't dig very deep.

- `HashSet.iterator()` returns `map.keySet().iterator()`
- `map.keySet()` returns a `HashMap.KeySet`
- `HashMap.KeySet.iterator()` calls `[HashMap.this.]newKeyIterator()`
- `LinkedHashMap` overrides `newKeyIterator().`

Comment: **HashMap.KeySet.iterator() calls [HashMap.this.]newKeyIterator()** - I am not agree. please read topic update

Comment: very messed architecture. I am very confused

Comment: You do not agree on what basis? It's right there in the source code. You quoted it yourself. No disagreement possible. You're arguing with the source code now, not with me. I can't help the architecture, and I certainly can't explain your confusion.

Comment: In my quote  **HashMap.KeySet.iterator()** invokes **newEntryIterator()**.  in yours **newKeyIterator()**.  What is right?

Comment: Your quote is wrong. Mine is correct. Have another look at the source code. Or possibly we are using different source code. It's hardly important. The basic idea is the final point.

Comment: Nobody said you've done anything wrong. You just haven't yet appreciated what I said above about the enclosing type and polymorphism.

Answer (score -1):

*LinkedHashSet* maintains insertion order, but *HashSet* doesn't. Quote from *LinkedHashSet*'s javadoc:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).

Any constructor of *LinkedHashSet* invokes super constructor of *HashSet*:

```
HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean dummy) {
    map = new LinkedHashMap<>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
}
```

And *LinkedHashMap* is hash table and linked list implementation of the *Map* interface, with predictable iteration order.

Comment: Yes, I know it. But I cannot find it in source code.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @user207421 you waited nine years to say that? Thanks for the downvote :)